# Ler retorno Array SELECT

Tags: php, json

Preciso retornar um array em formato JSON.

O Formato não é o problema.

O problema é pegar os index dos $row e exibir.

```
$db = new Connect;
$data = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM trabalhos_cientificos");

$data->execute();
$row = $data->fetch();
if( $row == null ){
    $users['message'] = "Sem assessorias.";
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode($users);
    exit();
}else{

 //$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data->fetch());
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data); //line 170
 foreach($row as $r) { //line 171
     $users[] = $r;
     echo json_encode($r['id_trabalhos_cientificos']);
 }
 echo json_encode(array('Data1' => $users));

 while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($data))) { //line 177
      $users[] = $row;
      echo json_encode($row['id_trabalhos_cientificos']);
 }
 echo json_encode(array('Data2' => $users));

http_response_code(200);
//echo json_encode($users);
//echo json_encode(array($users));
exit();

}
```

**Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/.../logado.php** on line **170**

**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/.../logado.php** on line **171**
{"Data1":[]}
**Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in **/opt/lampp/.../logado.php** on line **177**
{"Data2":[]}

[image: Retorno do meu select]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução foi usar o **fetchAll()** e **foreach($row as $r)**

```
$data->execute();
$row = $data->fetchAll();
if( $row == null ){
    $users['message'] = "Sem assessorias.";
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode($users);
    exit();
}
else{
  foreach($row as $r){
      $users[] = array(
        'idTrabalhosCientificos' => $r['id_trabalhos_cientificos']
                      );
 }
}
```

Comment: Você está usando [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ou [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)?

Comment: $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

Comment: Isso responde?  ou nao... ?

Comment: Você está usando `mysqli` então, mas a classe `mysqli` não possui o método `fetchAll`. Seu código está coletando dados do BD?  Não está com erro na linha `$row = $data->fetchAll();`?

Comment: Desculpe @WesleyGonçalves estou usando PDO.... **class Connect extends PDO**

Comment: Eu presumi que estava usando `mysqli` porque estava usando as funções `mysqli_fetch_array`, `mysqli_fetch_row` que têm relação com [*MySQL Improved Extension*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (classes [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) [`mysql_stmt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php), [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). Nesse caso, você precisa usar funções/métodos das classes [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) e [`PDOStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: vou ler sobre isso.... valew pela ajuda @WesleyGonçalves

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando a função `mysqli_fetch_array` que requer como primeiro parâmetro um objeto da classe `mysql_result` - como você pode ver na documentação [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). Mas você está passando `$data` que contém um objeto da classe [`mysqli_stmt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) - esse objeto foi retornado pela função [`mysqli::prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) na linha 2 (linha 158 do seu arquivo).

Você tem duas opções:

#### OPÇÃO 1

Acima de `mysqli_fetch_array` (linha 170 do seu arquivo), você invoca o método [`get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) da classe `mysqli_stmt`. Ele irá te retornar um objeto da classe `mysqli_result`.

```php
$result = $data->get_result();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// ...
```

Mas recomendo a opção 2.

#### OPÇÃO 2

Já que você já está lidando com Orientação a Objetos (classe `mysqli`, `mysqli_stmt`) é mais coerente e recomedável lidar com a classe `mysqli_result`.
Ao invés de usar a função `mysqli_fetch_array`, você pode usar o método `fetch_array` da classe `mysqli_result`. Aquela função e esse método têm a mesma função como você pode ver na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

```php
$result = $data->get_result();  // objeto da classe mysqli_result 
$row = $result->fetch_array();
```

---

O erro da linha 171 é devido a `$row` ter valor `null` devido ao erro da linha 170.

---

O erro da linha 177 é pelo mesmo motivo da linha 170.
Você pode usar o método `mysqli_result::fetch_row`.

#### Procedural

```php
 while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))) {
// ...
```

#### POO (RECOMENDADO)

```php
 while(($row = $result->fetch_row())) {
// ...
```

Comment: Veja sobre usar uma das flags `MYSQLI_ASSOC` ou `MYSQLI_NUM` no método `fetch_array` porque sem flags a funçao retorna um array com os dados duplicados (com índices numéricos e com índices que possuem o nome da coluna do BD).

Comment: a duplicidade já tratei no **select**

Comment: consegui de outra forma, vou postar

Comment: Essa duplicidade não tem relação com o MySQL SELECT, mas sim como `fetch_array` funciona.